# Can a recursive method have more than one base case in Pascal?

Tags: recursion, pascal

I was wondering if you can have more than just one base case on a recursive procedure/function in Pascal.
If so, can you please give me a **simple** example? And please explain why this is possible?

Comment: This is not really a Pascal-specific question. Regarding how to answer, think about what a base case does. In most languages, it's a check, within the recursive function, for certain conditions and, if met, will provide a result without having to resort to making the recursive call. Can there be more than one set of conditions that could lead to a non-recursive call case? I'll leave you to answer that question. Based upon that, it should be easy to contrive an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple Fibonacci sequence has two base cases:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
```

And, of course, you can write it in Pascal:

```
function Fib(n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n = 0 then Fib := 0
  else if n = 1 then Fib := 1
  else Fib := Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2)
end;
```